# Mysql reclaim mysql disk space after deleting rows

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

First of all sorry for repeatating this repeated question as it has been asked numerous times already. I have gone through those questions and answers.

I have a table on production environment of size approx 159 GB and now I want to migrate MySQL to another server. But since total DB size is more than 300 GB I am not able to migrate it easily. So I am trying to reclaim space by deleting records from MySQL. I deleted more than 70 % records from this table and tried `OPTIMIZE TABLE` but its giving an error as :

```
 mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;
+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| Table | Op | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| table_name | optimize | note | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| table_name | optimize | error | The table 'table_name' is full |
| table_name | optimize | status | Operation failed |
+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

innodb_file_per_table is set to ON

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_file_per_table%';
Variable_name          Value   
---------------------  --------
innodb_file_per_table  ON
```

Mysql Version: `5.7.28-log`

I read somewhere that `alter table` will help however it slows down all MySQL queries.

In one answer I read that copying data in another table and then renaming it and deleting original table (which I assume `OPTIMIZE TABLE` does internally) will help but doing so will need downtime.

Is there any other way which I can achieve this.?

Comment: @icecub Noted and edited the tags.

Comment: Already removed the comment. Now as for your question, do you have root access to the server that's hosting your database(s)?

Comment: @icecub yes I have the root access.

Comment: What operating system is running on the server? (so I know which resource to point you to). Most likely you're trying to migrate / backup a large database through phpmyadmin, which is not the way to do this.

Comment: Is it possible the drive is out of space?  For linux command prompt, df -h - will list all drive space available, used with %.  For Windows command prompt, cd (datadir); DIR will show used / free space.

Comment: @icecub we are using linux.

Comment: Ok login as root to your server. Then do `mysql -u root -p`. This should prompt you for your mysql root password. Change root in that command to some other mysql username if you have to, just make sure it has access to the database(s) you're trying to migrate. Once logged in, do `mysqldump --quick db_name | gzip > db_name.gz`. Change db_name to your database name. Move the GZ file to a location where you can download it (ftp dir for example): `mv db_name.gz /path/to/ftp/dir`. Then download it. Upload to new server. Login to mysql again the same way. Create db: `mysqladmin create db_name`

Comment: And lastly get the database from the file into your newly created database: `gunzip < /path/to/db_name.gz | mysql db_name` Reference for all of this: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html)

Comment: yes. but it will take lot of time. Also since application is already running doing so will not be able to dump updated data on another server without downtime.

Comment: Will you be migrating to the _same_ version of MySQL?  Are you hoping to copy files?  Or using some dump (mysqldump/xtrabackup/etc)?

Comment: How big is ibdata1?  (It may be large due to previous activity.)

Comment: @RickJames ibdata1 size is 1.7 GB .

Regarding how I am planning to do?

1. One way is to take mysqldump and restore on another server. But I have time constraints to keep system down. And doesn't seem feasible considering the DB size. 

2. Another one is through master slave sync (which will again require mysqldump and restore) but again since size is huge its taking lot of time.

So the only choice I am left with is to reduce the size.

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe - What is your "disaster plan"?  That is, what will you do if there is a power failure?  Or an unrecoverable disk crash?